# How to use apache spark in extising Web application

Tags: java, apache, apache-spark-sql

How can I use **Apache spark** into my existing Web application?
It's deployed on Apache Tomcat and the application is developed in Java.

How can I use spark? Is there any configuration that is required?

Comment: You want migrate total application to Spark from Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Livy server](https://github.com/cloudera/livy)

Your server will be it's client, or you can use code examples from it and implement it inside your server. 
I have a ruby server that calls livy - run a job and read from log - where to get the results from (s3).